# How to set initial generator value?

Tags: firebird

I need to initialise a new Firebird generator / sequence to the max primary key value of an existing, 'old' table. I tried the following but it is not working, I get the error "Token unknown - line 6, column 8 select". I cannot do this manually as it must be executed on many different DBs. I am using Firebird 2.5.1.

According to http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-execblock.html this should work - what am I doing wrong?

```sql
set term #;  
execute block  
as  
declare i int = 0;  
begin  
   i = select max(ID) from OrganizationType_OLU;  
    alter sequence OrganizationType_OLU restart with :i;  
end  
#  
set term ;#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set term #;
execute block    
as  
declare i int = 0;    
declare temp int = 0;
begin  
  i = (select max(id) from items);  
  temp = gen_id(GEN_ITEMS_ID,-(gen_id(GEN_ITEMS_ID,0))); ---set some_gen to 0  
  temp = gen_id(GEN_ITEMS_ID,:i);  --- set to i
end #  
set term ;#
```

Comment: Thank you, this got me into the right direction. The fully working SQL looks like this:set term #;
execute block
as
declare i int = 0;
declare g int = 0;
begin
   i = (select max(ID) from OrganizationType_OLU);
   g = (select gen_id(OrganizationType_OLU,-(gen_id(OrganizationType_OLU,0))) from RDB$DATABASE);
   g = (select gen_id(OrganizationType_OLU,(select max(ID) from OrganizationType_OLU)) from RDB$DATABASE);
end
#
set term ;#

Answer (score 6):

In general you can use [`ALTER SEQUENCE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-sequence-alter):

```
ALTER SEQUENCE sequence-name RESTART WITH <newval>
```

Or the legacy option [`SET GENERATOR`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-sequence-setgen)

```
SET GENERATOR generator-name TO <new-value>
```

However you want to do this from an `EXECUTE BLOCK` and you can't as executing DDL from PSQL code isn't allowed in Firebird. So I guess the [answer of rstrelba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16056992/466862) is probably the only option available.

Be aware though that sequences are outside of transaction control in Firebird (they are atomic), so make sure you only run it if you are the only active transaction, otherwise you might reset the sequence to an invalid value.

I strongly suggest to make sure the `ID` for `OrganizationType_OLU` is always generated by sequence, and never allow user specified values for these columns. This ensures that the sequence value is always valid (ie: not too low, causing primary key constraint violations).

Answer (score 1):

The error you got (`Token unknown - line 6, column 8 select`) is because if you want to use [`select` as an expression](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-psql-subquery-as-expr.html) you have to enclose it into parenthesis like

```
i = (select max(ID) from OrganizationType_OLU);
```

Comment: Thank you, this got my line 7 going.

Answer (score 1):

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE fMaxID INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id),0)
    FROM yourtable
    INTO :fMaxID ;

    EXECUTE STATEMENT('CREATE SEQUENCE YourSequence');
    EXECUTE STATEMENT('ALTER SEQUENCE YourSequence RESTART WITH '||CAST(:fMaxID AS VARCHAR(16)));
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you do not want to use `EXECUTE BLOCK`** or if you still use an older Firebird version (<2.0), try this:

Given, that `GEN_ITEMS_ID` is your generator name, you can set the initial generator value by the following DML statement:

```
SELECT GEN_ID(GEN_ITEMS_ID, 
  (select max(ID) from OrganizationType_OLU) 
  - GEN_ID(GEN_ITEMS_ID, 0)) FROM RDB$DATABASE;
```

Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004506/2306907).