# Initialize generator with existing value

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I am trying to set a generator with a value that is in some table, I have already seen this question [How to set initial generator value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056556/firebird-how-to-set-initial-generator-value/16056992#16056992) and did what they suggested but I don't know where am I going wrong here.

```sql
set term #   
execute block    
as  
declare i int = 0;    
begin  
  i = (select max(some_col) from Table);  
  gen_id(some_gen,-(gen_id(some_gen,0))); ---set some_gen to 0  
  gen_id(some_gen,:i);  --- set to i
end #  
set term ;#
```

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do, what you expect and what actually happens. Note that meddling with sequences (generators) is usually a sign of a bad design, or abusing them for things they shouldn't be used for.

Comment: I am just trying to set the generator value to the max value of some column in a table, same as this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056556/how-to-set-initial-generator-value/16056992#16056992 just that I am getting an SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 37
(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you can't execute `gen_id` in isolation; the parser expects `gen_id` (or more precisely: a function call) only in a place where you can have a value (eg in a statement or an assignment). You need to assign its return value to a parameter, for example:

```sql
set term #;
execute block    
as  
declare i int = 0;    
declare temp int = 0;
begin  
  i = (select max(id) from items);  
  temp = gen_id(GEN_ITEMS_ID, -(gen_id(GEN_ITEMS_ID, 0))); ---set some_gen to 0  
  temp = gen_id(GEN_ITEMS_ID, :i);  --- set to i
end #  
set term ;#
```

Please be aware that changing sequences like this is 'risky': if there are any interleaving actions using this same sequence, you might not actually get the result you expected (the sequence might end up at a different value than `i` and you might get duplicate key errors when another transaction uses the sequence after you subtract the current value (set to `0`) and before you add `i`.

As also noted in the comments, you can also replace your code with:

```sql
set term #;
execute block    
as  
declare i int = 0;    
declare temp int = 0;
begin  
  i = (select max(id) from items);  
  temp = gen_id(GEN_ITEMS_ID, :i - gen_id(GEN_ITEMS_ID, 0));
end #  
set term ;#
```

Doing it in one statement will reduce the risk of interleaving operations (although it will not remove it entirely).

Comment: I have also edited the [answer on the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056556/how-to-set-initial-generator-value/16056992#16056992), but note that the actual solution was already mentioned in the comment of Daniel Putra on that answer.

Comment: Is it necessary first to set the generator to 0 and then to some value?

Comment: @ValMarinov Not really, you can also do `gen_id(GEN_ITEMS_ID, :i - (gen_id(GEN_ITEMS_ID, 0)))`, it reduces the risk of interleaving actions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Now is better. +1 for this. Although I would prefer to do it without using the function "gen_id"

Comment: @ValMarinov I know, but `gen_id` is the only thing flexible enough to do this without having to resort to dynamic sql and `execute statement`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel just for interest sake, is there an alternate solution for achieving this without using the Execute statement?

Comment: @Fero68 No, but then again: you really shouldn't be doing this anyway. Don't be afraid of gaps in your ids.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use "execute block", you may use something like :

```
execute block    
as  
declare i int = 0;    
begin  
  i = (select max(some_col) from some_table);
  execute statement ('set generator MY_GENERATOR to ' || :i);
end
```